# How to interact with ST-Link server (not the ST-Link GDB server)

Tags: debugging, gdb, embedded, stm32

I currently write some code for a STM32 board and stumbled across some different debug utilities which confused me a bit.
The way I debugged software for the ST boards was by using the ST Link GDB Server which comes with the CubeIDE. I connected my arm-none-eabi-gdb client to it and with that I could step through my code - perfectly fine.

Now I saw that there is also a separate ST Link Server available for download from the ST website. I downloaded it but there is no User Manual, no reference manual and not a single hint how you can interact with the ST-Link server. All i can find out is that it listens on port 7184 for something but it seems like it's not a GDB server. The only relevant thing it says on the website is

> The ST-LINK server is an application to share the debug interface of a single ST-LINK board among several host applications, typically a debugging tool and a monitoring tool.

That's great, but what are those monitoring tools ? What do they mean with a "typically debugging tool" ? And how can I interact with the ST-Link server ?

The reasons I ask this is because I wanted to use some debug features which are supported by the ST-Link probe, but not by GDB and I thought maybe with the "normal" ST-Link server I can get those working.

Comment: No it is not an extended gdb.

Comment: It is a relay which lets you to share one USB probe. It does not enable any advanced debug features.

Comment: Ok thanks, that helps me a bit. Anyway, if it doesn't add more debug features i think it's the wrong tool for me. I would still be curious to know how for example the IAR Embedded Workbench achieves those advanced debug features with the st link probe. I throught it would use the st-link server but that's obviously wrong now.

Comment: Which features are you seeking?  What's the usual way of achieving them?

Comment: https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um2576-stm32cubeide-stlink-gdb-server-stmicroelectronics.pdf - still nothing useful in the provided document